# Returning from Array.prototype.map() is not consistent

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get this output `['1', '12', '123']` from:

```
   getSubstrings('123');

   function getSubstrings(string) {
      let array = string.split('');
      let subarray = [];
      return array.map(element => {
        subarray.push(element);
        console.log(subarray)       //this gets me ['1'], then ['1','2'] ...
        return subarray;            //but this is not returning the same as in console.log(subarray)   
      });
      
    }
```

I know I can get the result I want by adding `.join('')` to the end of `subarray`. My question is not about how to get `['1', '12', '123']` But, why returning the same subarray as the one being outputted on the console would result in `[[1','2','3'], ['1','2','3'], ['1','2','3']]` instead of `[[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]` weird enough, the output from the console.log(subarray) is not the same as the returning subarray populated in the .map() Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it's the same array, how can it be different in each place in the result?

Comment: Returning an array doesn't make a copy of it.

Comment: Arrays in JS are objects, objects in JS are passed by reference.  eg. `var a = [1,2,3]; b = a; a.push(4); console.log(b);`  You might expect this to say `1,2,3`, but it says `1,2,3,4`.. Because b was just a reference to a.

Comment: `[...'123'].map((_, i, a)=>a.slice(0,i+1).join(''))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that subarray is changing in each map 'iteration', because you are not creating a new subarray, just passing the same reference to return. It will change all the three cases.

First, it returns `[1]`, but then it returns `[1,2]` and change the first to `[1,2]`. Same happens with last element. Finally, you'd have an array made by three copies of the same reference (subarray).

Fix it by the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
function getSubstrings(string) {
      let array = string.split('');
      let subarray = [];
      return array.map(element => {
        subarray.push(element);
        return [...subarray].join(""); // join to get the desired output  
      });
    }

console.log(getSubstrings("123"))
```

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Don't mention it! If it helped you can consider giving me an upvote (plz, I need reputation :D)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the subarray is being modify in every iteration and is not creating a new subarray. so what it actually happening is that you're passing the exact same reference to return, hence resulting in changing all results.

I suggest to refactor this to use forEach, something like this:

```js
   const arr = getSubstrings('123');

   function getSubstrings(string) {
      let array = string.split('');
      let mainArray = [];
      let cur = '';
      array.forEach(x => {
         cur += x;
         mainArray.push(cur);
      })
      return mainArray;
    }
    
    console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I just realized the array is getting mutated when passed around. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate if you can upvote the answer and accept it (: